# How do I fix broken packages after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 when "apt upgrade", "apt --fix-broken install", and many other solutions fail?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 22.04

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 earlier today, and the upgrade to 20.04 seemed smooth enough, so I thought I might as well avoid migration pains later this summer and upgrade to 22.04 now.

I upgraded 20.04 to 22.04 when logged in. It appears as if the installation had completed while I was logged in, which was weird.

I wasn't able to view folders in the filesystem via GUI, so I restarted the computer, and I got the Ubuntu loading screen, followed by a blank screen that eventually showed that the Samba Daemon could not start.

I restarted the computer, and then logged in as root in recovery mode. It appears as if I have about 176 broken packages, which appear to have various conflicts and breaks. e.g., `libcurl14:amd64 Conflicts on libcurl13:amd64 < 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 @pi mK Ib >`.

I've tried all of the following:

```
apt autoremove
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
# any of the above result in the following error:
# E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

apt --fix-broken install
# E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
# E: Unable to correct dependencies

dpkg --configure -a
# dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
#  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
# Errors were encountered while processing:
#  qgis-providers
```

I'm not sure if there's a clean solution to this, or if I should just nuke the installation and backup the data (which most of it is, anyway), then reinstall it.

Comment: It might help if you clarify; Ubuntu 16.04 could upgrade to 16.10 (next release) or 18.04 (next LTS), but had no upgrade path to 20.04... so are you using [Ubuntu Upgrade tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) as it seems you're not, thus problems are likely related to how you're upgrading...

Comment: I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04, and 18.04 to 20.04. I had to fix a lot of broken packages for 18.04, and remove a few ones (like Skype) to do the second upgrade.